# asp.net Ajax Toolkit CascadingDropdown - Unknown web method

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, asp.net-4.0

I am trying to use a very basic CascadingDropDown from Ajax Control Toolkit. What I am trying to implement is let the user select "State" and "City" from dropdowns. The CascadingDropDown code is shown below.

```
    State : <asp:DropDownList ID="DdlState" runat="server" />
    <asp:CascadingDropDown ID="CddState" runat="server" TargetControlID="DdlState" Category="State"
    EmptyText="Select State" EmptyValue="0" ServiceMethod="GetDropDownContents" 
    />

    City : <asp:DropDownList ID="DdlCity" runat="server" />
    <asp:CascadingDropDown ID="CddCity" runat="server" TargetControlID="DdlCity" ParentControlID="DdlState" Category="City"
    EmptyText="Select City" EmptyValue="0" ServiceMethod="GetDropDownContents"
    />
```

and Here is what i have in code-behind

```
[WebMethod]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod]
public CascadingDropDownNameValue[] GetDropDownContents(string knownCategoryValues, string category) {
    if (category.Equals("State")) {
        StateManager stateManager = new StateManager(null);
        List<CascadingDropDownNameValue> states = new List<CascadingDropDownNameValue>();
        foreach (State state in stateManager.GetQueryableStates().ToList()) {
            states.Add(new CascadingDropDownNameValue(state.Name, state.Id.ToString()));
        }
        return states.ToArray();
    } else {
        CityManager cityManager = new CityManager(null);
        List<CascadingDropDownNameValue> cities = new List<CascadingDropDownNameValue>();
        foreach (City city in cityManager.GetQueryableCities()
                             .Where(c => c.State.Id == 1))) {
            cities.Add(new CascadingDropDownNameValue(city.Name,city.Id.ToString()));
        }
        return cities.ToArray();
    }
}
```

The above code is failing with 500 Internal Server Error. Using fiddler I can see the following error **"Unknown web method GetDropDownContents"**. But I already have the web method GetDropDownContents() in my code-behind file and is also marked as [WebMethod].

So, why does the populate dropdown request not find the Web Method that I have in code-behind file.

**Update**
Here is the link to the Demo [CascadingDropDown](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/CascadingDropDown/CascadingDropDown.aspx)

**Update-2**
The Class Declaration.

```
public partial class Index : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    ....
}
```

Comment: do you are using a webservice?

Comment: No. I have the method in my code-behind file

Comment: Ok,  in the example uses a webservice, and you're using a class that inherits from System.Web.UI.Page or not? Could you show us the declaration of the class that contains the method GetDropDownContents

Comment: I'm updated the answer, I still think you need a static method. Yours    ServiceMethod=GetDropDownContents and  ServicePath=index.aspx in <ajaxToolkit:CascadingDropDown tag?

Comment: Here's a scenario like yours http://forums.asp.net/t/1158057.aspx/1 and http://www.mikeborozdin.com/post/Static-Page-Methods-Instead-of-Web-Services-in-ASPNET-AJAX-Control-Toolkit.aspx

Answer (score 2):

The `GetDropDownContents` method must be static

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a scriptmanager with pagemethods enabled on your Page?

Comment: Could be an answer if it helps hin solve his Problem! So don't know yet :-P

Comment: @NikolajZander I do have the ScriptManager.